# Increasing sequence combinatorics with weightings

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I want to evaluate the following quantity, or at least provide a reasonably tight upper bound.

$$ \sum_{1 \leq t_1 < t_2 < \dots < t_n \leq q} \frac{1}{(t_1 + 1)(t_2 + 1)\dots(t_n + 1)} $$
I have thought about considering cases where all $t_i$ were allowed to range freely from $1$ to $q$, then dividing by $n!$ for repeated permutations and substracting instances where at minimum two  $t_i$s were identical. However, this just leads to a combinatorics problem of instances when $t_i = t_j$ for any pair, not overcounting for $t_i = t_j = t_k$, and so on. Any ideas?

Comment: You can make it $2\leq t_1<\cdots<q+1$ and remove the $+1$s in the denominator.

Comment: This will be related to the polynomials $(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+q+1).$ Specifically, the coefficient of $x^{q-n}$ divided by $(q+1)!$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Here are those numerators: https://oeis.org/A143491